# SAS combining datasets, binary search, indices

Tags: loops, dataset, sas, indices

In SAS, for the two test datasets below - for every value of "amount" that falls within "y" and "z", I need to extract the corresponding "x". There could be multiple values of "x" that fit into the criteria.
The final result should look something like this:

```
/*
4 banana eggs
15 .
31 .
7 banana
22 fig
1 eggs
11 coconut
17 date
41 apple
*/
```

I realize this relies on using indices or binary searches but I can't figure out a workable solution! Any help would appreciated! Thanks!

```
data test1;
   input x $ y z;
   datalines;
   apple 29 43
   banana 2 7
   coconut 9 13
   date 17 20
   eggs 1 5
   fig 18 26
   ;
run;

data test2;
   input amount;
   datalines;
   4
   15
   31
   7
   22
   1
   11
   17
   41
   ;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two datasets so `amount` falls between `y` and `z`.

```
proc sql;
create table join as 
select a.amount
      ,b.*
from test2 a
       left join
     test1 b
       on a.amount between b.y and b.z;
quit;
```

Sort the result by amount for transpose.

```
proc sort data=join; by amount; run;
```

Transpose it.

```
proc transpose data=join out=trans;
by amount;
var x;
run;
```

Now you have your fruits each in its own variable named `col1`, `col2`, ....
If you want them all in one variable separated by a blank, just concatenate them.

```
data trans2(keep= amount text);
set trans(drop=_name_);
array v{*} _character_;
text = catx(' ', of v{*});
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using "old-fashioned" data step code plus `PROC TRANSPOSE`:

```
data test1;
    input x $ y z;
    datalines;
    apple 29 43
    banana 2 7
    coconut 9 13
    date 17 20
    eggs 1 5
    fig 18 26
run;

data test2;
    input amount;
    datalines;
    4
    15
    31
    7
    22
    1
    11
    17
    41
run;

data want(keep=amount x);
   set test2;
   found = 0;
   do _i_=1 to nobs;
      set test1 point=_i_ nobs=nobs;
      if y <= amount <= z then do;
         found = 1;
         output;
         end;
      end;
   if not found then do;
      x = ' ';
      output;
      end;
run;

proc transpose data=want out=want2(drop=_name_);
   by amount notsorted;
   var x;
run;
```

Note my results do not match that in your example; amount 31 is an "apple".

Comment: Thank you so much! This works just as well as the solution above!  And you're right, amount 31 is an "apple" - that was an error on my part!